# How to paste specific cells in .bat file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have this Code that Exports all my Excel values  into .bat Format, i am trying to Export all the values except the headers. This is the Code :

```
Public Sub Export_File_as_BAT()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")     
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                      
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\User_Tableau.bat", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Sheets("Export").Select
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

I cant seem to fix it. Any Help will be appriciated.

Thank you

This is an example on what i am trying to do.
[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Nrl.png)

Comment: I guess you have Headers in Row 1 ,, if so then skip Row 1,, write `Range("A2").Select`.

Comment: I do that, and still it pastes all the values :S

Comment: Why not just create a TXT-based .BAT or .CMD file, write the lines then close the file?

Comment: @Eidrizi ,, are you exporting /Copying Sheet data to new Workbook or  to Text File?

Comment: @Eidrizi,, please write how many Columns & Rows you want to COPY as BAT file !

Comment: @RajeshS , thanks for Reply, i Need range("A2:D16") to be pasted as BAT file.

Comment: @Jeeped i Need the Excel so everyone in the Department  just can open the file and Input the valus and juist Export it. i will Input a picutre now so you can see it.

Comment: You may try this,, `Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D16").Copy _
    Workbooks("Export.bat").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")` ,, hope this help you!

Comment: @RajeshS thank you for the script, the Code doesnt work, it gives me error that the subscript is out of range. i also tried to Input **Range("A2:D16").copy** in front of _shToEcport.... Before:=..._ but it gives me also error. it wont let me do it, and when i remove completly _Before....._ it works but then when i open .bat file as .txt to check it , ti Shows nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101872/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-eidrizi).

Comment: Why not run the value in A2 as a VBA shell command? Are there supposed to be additional commands in the BAT/CMD?

Comment: @Jeeped no, not additional command inside CMD , user insert the credetials in Excel form and then Exports it in .bat and then runs it.

Comment: Then just have the button run the command in a [VBA shell command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function).

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this VBA code as Standard Module:*

```
Sub Export2BAT()

    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = InputBox("Enter Name Of New Workbok", "Workbook Name")
    If Trim(strFileName) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Range("A2:D16").Copy
    Sheets.Add.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Your Path Here\" & strFileName & ".bat", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Respond the INPUT BOX with New Workbook name (First Name only).
- You may use this code with Command Button also.
- Range `A2:D16` and destination Wbook Range `A1` are editable.